# Set default format of datetimepicker as dd-MM-yyyy

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a datetimepicker which on loading of windows form shows me format in 'MM-dd-yyyy',

as follows:

[image]

I would like it in `dd-MM-yyyy`.

I tried the following:

set custom format: `"dd-MM-yyyy"`

But Its not changing.

What could be the problem?

Please help me.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Ensure that control Format property is properly set to use a custom format:

```
DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
```

Then this is how you can set your desired format:

```
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

Comment: *both of which can be set in the properties window

Comment: @ThirdBattleOfPanipat - to use a custom format you have to set .Format AND .CustomFormat.

Comment: @dbasnett only dtpDate.Format.Custom option is there

Comment: Clean as a whistle!

Answer (score 37):

Ammending as "optional Answer". If you don't need to programmatically solve the problem, here goes the "visual way" in VS2012.

In Visual Studio, you can set custom format directly from the properties Panel:
[image]

First Set the "Format" property to: "Custom";
Secondly, set your custom format to: "dd-MM-yyyy";

Comment: this way you can also set Format to Short if the Culture Information contains the desired behavior. e.g. German Culture *short* will bring *dd.MM.yyyy*

Answer (score 12):

You could easily use:

`label1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

and if you want to change '/' or '-', just add this:

`label1.Text = label1.Text.Replace(".", "-")`

More info about **DateTimePicker.CustomFormat Property**: [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

Try this,

```
string Date = datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

It worked for me the output format will be '02-May-2016'

Answer (score 3):

You can set CustomFormat property to "dd-MM-yyyy" in design mode and use dateTimePicker1.Text property to fetch string in "dd/MM/yyyy" format irrespective of display format.