# Override shown placeholder by DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

What's the easiest way to override the default value that's shown by `DateTimePicker`.

I mean it shows `7/31/2018` by default, but I'd like it to show `DD/MM/YYYY` by default, to let users know what is the required pattern to `DateTime`. 

**Not format, I talking about exactly the shown value.**

**So to show 'D', 'D', '/', 'M', 'M', '/', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'** characters.

My best idea is to make my own DateTimePicker by `UserControl`.

Is there any better solution to my problem?

So the DateTimePicker looks like this now:

[image]

But I'd like it to show this by default:

[image]

Comment: The format shown by default is the computer's regional format. If you are shown `MM/dd/yyyy`, your computer is most likely in that format as well

Comment: I'm no talking about the format. I talking about the exact shown value.

Comment: That's exactly what the format is, the text displayed on the control. The value is a `DateTime` instance which doesn't have a format.

Comment: Have you tried setting `MyPicker.Value' ?

Comment: Updated with pictures.

Comment: There is still a format problem.  The first image shows mm/dd/yyyy, but you want the user to input dd/mm/yyyy.  Which is it?

Comment: Omg. Are you joking now or really don't understand the issue?

Comment: if question about place holder, change your question. And add that you want placeholder.
If you want custom datetime format see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466805/set-default-format-of-datetimepicker-as-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Placeholder, I'd like to write placeholder, just foget the word. But I stated with bold, that I'm not talking about format. Ty anyway.

Comment: If you want placeholder for winforsm you may write custom controler such https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ee0c5fbe-8d18-4899-8df2-46535b570bb4/how-to-create-a-nullable-and-editable-datetimepicker?forum=winforms

Comment: @KreminT thanks, the msdn forum link solved my problem! If you post it as answer, I accept it.

Comment: @koviroli i posted answer

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you need **placeholder** with text "*DD/MM/YYYY*",But **Placeholders are not supported** in windows predefined controls, you have to create **custom control** if you need placeholder in winforms.

> Create custom control for calendar and customize it as per your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

At the start of your program, set the culture to be UK (or whatever you require):

```
void Main()
{
   CultureInfo.Current = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

}
```

You may also need to set the culture of the current thread.  [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) gives more information.

Comment: Not format, I talking about exactly the shown value.

Comment: It's a confusing question because the value you show is mm/dd/yyyy and you want to show dd/mm/yyyy.  Which format is correct?